# Why the top couple of buttons aren't showing in my layout?

Tags: android, layout, android-viewpager, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have a `LinearLayout`, containg a `ScrollView` of `ViewFlipper` layouts. I've only included the problematic layout within my `ViewFlipper`. For some reason the top couple of buttons aren't showing, from `gps1` upwards. Does anyone know why this is?

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dip">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="false">
        <ViewFlipper 
            android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--adding views to ViewFlipper-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/accelerometer1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:onClick="getAccelerometer"
                    android:text="Get Accelerometer">
                </Button>

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/gps1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:onClick="getLocation"
                    android:text="Get GPS">
                </Button>

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/picture1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:onClick="takePicture"
                    android:text="Take picture">
                </Button>

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/video1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:onClick="takeVideo"
                    android:text="Take video">
                </Button>

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/picture2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:onClick="takePicture"
                    android:text="Take picture">
                </Button>

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/audio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:onClick="takeAudio"
                    android:text="Take audio">
                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Page 1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Question 1?"/>

                <EditText android:id="@+id/textbox1" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:text=""/>

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/gps2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:onClick="getLocation"
                    android:text="Get GPS">
                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Question 2?" />

                <EditText android:id="@+id/textbox2" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:text=""/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Question 3?" />

                <EditText android:id="@+id/textbox3" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:text=""/>
            </LinearLayout>
            </ViewFlipper>
            </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I ended up taking out `layout_gravity:center` from the `ViewFlipper` attributes which solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out myself. I took out the `layout-gravity:center` attribute from my ViewFlipper:

```
<ViewFlipper 
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out, added some margin.. :)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="30dip">
   <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="false">
    <ViewFlipper 
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <!--adding views to ViewFlipper-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/accelerometer1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:onClick="getAccelerometer"
                android:text="Get Accelerometer">
            </Button>

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/gps1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:onClick="getLocation"
                android:text="Get GPS">
            </Button>

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/picture1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:onClick="takePicture"
                android:text="Take picture">
            </Button>

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/video1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:onClick="takeVideo"
                android:text="Take video">
            </Button>

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/picture2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:onClick="takePicture"
                android:text="Take picture">
            </Button>

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/audio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:onClick="takeAudio"
                android:text="Take audio">
            </Button>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Page 1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Question 1?"/>

            <EditText android:id="@+id/textbox1" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:text=""/>

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/gps2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:onClick="getLocation"
                android:text="Get GPS">
            </Button>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Question 2?" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/textbox2" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:text=""/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Question 3?" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/textbox3" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:text=""/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </ViewFlipper>
        </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This does work, but I was hoping for a more concrete solution, maybe adjusting the views somehow? The margins will probably need to be different for each layout.

Comment: Your you see your view flipper is going above then the screen, see  it and adjust it accordingly, the problem was your View(Button) was getting overlaped.
if it helped you please mark as accepted, or vote it up...:)thanks